# firebase express cloud functions cors errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying like crazy to get this firebase http function to work with cors. Basically, I am serving the admin sdk locally to verify if a certain user token has admin claims to it. The token is sent via a get request as a parameter in the url. I am currently getting a 404 error and a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. I have tried rearranging my code bunch of different ways including how firebase does it in the documentation but always end up getting that cors along with either a 404 or 500 error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const corsOptions = {
                origin: '*',
                allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Content-Length', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept'],
                methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
                optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
    };
let app = express()
app.use(cors);

app.get('/AdminSignIn/:token',(req, res) => {
   cors(corsOptions,(req,res) =>{
       admin.auth.verifyIdToken(req.params.token).then((claims) => {
           console.log(claims.admin)
           if(claims.admin == true){
               res.send(true)
           }else{
               res.send(false)
           }
       })
   })
})

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.AdminSignIn = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply cors as *both* express middleware *and* inline in the function?  Seems like you'd just want one or the other.

Comment: Have you tried adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` as part of your headers?

Comment: Doesn't the cors middleware already do that for you?

Comment: I'm getting the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821401/cors-error-within-a-cloud-function still no fix for me

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of issues with CORS and firebase functions, both with and without Express. What I have noticed is *sometimes* after function deployment, CORS errors creep back in, which isn't fantastic, and seemingly unpredictable. There may not be anything wrong with your CORS implementation.

I think there may be a caching issue with firebase deployment? I'm able to fix these CORS errors with function deletion and then redeployment.

I realize this isn't much of a solution, but if nothing is working and you are really stressed out and frustrated, this may help!

Comment: Same happening to me. A delete and redeploy seems to fix this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your responses to `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send(true)` and `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').send(false)`.

Also I think `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` should be immediately after `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`